# MMASetup Command Line Parameters for SCOM

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, azure-log-analytics, scom, oms

I'm installing the latest MMASetup-AMD64.exe and want to hook up to Log Analytics AND SCOM.  But, I'm having trouble finding the command line parameters for SCOM.  Does anybody know them?  The Log Analytics ones are well documented and are here:

ADD_OPINSIGHTS_WORKSPACE=1

OPINSIGHTS_WORKSPACE_ID="1234"

OPINSIGHTS_WORKSPACE_KEY="5678"

I need the equivalent parameters for management group name and management server.  Effectively completing these boxes but via the command line.

[image: SCOM Install Options]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe parameters for management group, secure port, etc. are not available with MMASetup-AMD64.exe. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/agent-windows#install-the-agent-using-the-command-line) are the supported command line options with it. So may be, if its feasible in your environment and setup, try to use MOMAgent.msi to install agent manually or to deploy System Center Operations Manager agents from the command line or by using the Setup Wizard. The parameters like MANAGEMENT_GROUP, SECURE_PORT, etc. are all explained along with examples in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/scom/manage-deploy-windows-agent-manually?view=sc-om-2019) document. For more information, please refer it.

Other references related to OM agents and OM groups:

- [Process manual agent installations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/scom/manage-process-manual-agent-install?view=sc-om-2019)
- [Configuring Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/scom/manage-deploy-config-windows-agent?view=sc-om-2019)
- [Operations Manager agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/scom/plan-planning-agent-deployment?view=sc-om-2019)
- [Creating and managing groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/scom/manage-create-manage-groups?view=sc-om-2019)
- [Connecting management groups in Operations Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/scom/manage-connecting-mgmtgroups?view=sc-om-2019)
- [Planning a Management Group Design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/system-center/scom/plan-mgmt-group-design?view=sc-om-2019)